# issue in analysis using decision tree algorithm in Spark and Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, apache-spark, decision-tree, pyspark

I am doing a `churn` analysis for telecom industry and I have a sample dataset. I have written this code below where I am using `decision tree` algorithm in `Spark` through `python`. In the dataset I have multiple columns and I am selecting the columns that I need for my `feature` set.

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree, DecisionTreeModel
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
import os.path
import numpy as np


inputPath = os.path.join('file1.csv')
file_name = os.path.join(inputPath)
data = sc.textFile(file_name).zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (line,rownum): rownum>0).map(lambda (line, rownum): line)


final_data = data.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).filter(lambda line: len(line)>1).map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(1 if line[5] == 'True' else 0,[line[6],line[7]]))

(trainingdata, testdata) = final_data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

model = DecisionTree.trainRegressor(trainingdata, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                    impurity='variance', maxDepth=5, maxBins=32)

predictions = model.predict(testdata.map(lambda x: x.features))
prediction= predictions.collect()

labelsAndPredictions = testData.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)
```

Now this code works fine and does the prediction but what I am missing is the identifier for each customer in the `prediction` set or `testdata`. In my dataset there is a column for `customerid` (column number 4) which as of now I am not selecting as its not a feature to be considered in the model. I am having difficulty in associating this `customerid` column with the `testdata` for the customers whose detail is in the `testdata`. If I add this select this column from the dataset in the `feature` vector I am forming in the `LabeledPoint` then this would lead to error as its not a feature value.

How can I add this column in my analysis so that I can get say top 50 customers who have higher churn value?

Comment: @zero323 can you help me in telling how exactly I do that as I am new to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it exactly the same way as you add the label after prediction.

Small helper:

```
customerIndex = ... # Put index of the column

def extract(line):
    """Given a line create a tuple (customerId, labeledPoint)"""
    label = 1 if line[5] == 'True' else 0
    point =  LabeledPoint(label, [line[6], line[7]])
    customerId = line[customerIndex]
    return (customerId, point)
```

Prepare date using the `extract` function:

```
final_data = (data
    .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    .filter(lambda line: len(line) >1 )
    .map(extract)) # Map to tuples
```

Train:

```
# As before
(trainingdata, testdata) = final_data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Use only points, put the rest of the arguments in place of ...
model = DecisionTree.trainRegressor(trainingdata.map(lambda x: x[1]), ...)
```

Predict:

```
# Make predictions using points
predictions = model.predict(testdata.map(lambda x: x[1].features))

# Add customer id and label
labelsIdsAndPredictions = (testData
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].label))
    .zip(predictions))
```

Extract top 50:

```
top50 = labelsIdsAndPredictions.top(50, key=lambda x: x[1])
```